# Why if I call a WebService with ScriptManager it returns json?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json, web-services

I defined this ScriptManager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/webservices/WSModuloSocial.asmx" InlineScript="true" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

if I call a WebService function from the website (using it) it returns as json.
But if I call the same WebService function from another domain (with jquery, Access-Control-Allow-Origin policy on) it returns XML.

Who convert XML to JSON? And where should I convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your request to the server you can specify what you want back. The server probably accepts json and xml as return type.

In your request to the server specify in the header of your request the Content-Type

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

> question: Who converts XML to JSON?
>
> answer: the server does, but on your specification
>
> question: And where should I convert ?
>
> answer: you don't, just specify the Content-Type

Answer (score 0):

The format for both the request and the response can be specified either using the Content-Type header, the Accept header or adding an .xml or .json extension to the request URI.

If conflicting formats are specified in headers and/or format extensions, the latter takes precedence. XML is currently the default format for both requests and responses.

JSON is the default data format used by ScriptManager control created in Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).

This format can also be used when creating WebServices without integrating with ASP.NET - in this case, XML is the default but JSON can be chosen.